# What is the domain and range of $f(x,y)=3x^2+2y^2-5$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

What is the domain and range of $f(x,y)=3x^2+2y^2-5$

I'm just starting to learn multivariable, and need help on this question.

---

Let $z=3x^2+2y^2-5$

The domain is $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x,y\in(-\infty,\infty)\}$

There is no restriction on the domain.

What about the range?

I can't really imagine this curve and so I don't know for which values of $z$ it can cover. How can I solve this?

Comment: If the domain is the real numbers then $x^2\ge 0$ and $y^2\ge 0.$  What does that say about the minimal value of $f$?

Comment: I guess the maximal value is unbounded, but perhaps the minimum value is $z=-5$?

Comment: @KSplitX You got it!

Comment: Thank you both of you

Comment: One more question. What about the range in set notation. What is $z$ an element of? $z$ is just a number, and so $z\in\mathbb{R}$, but $z=f(x,y)$, and so $z\in\mathbb{R}^3$. I think it is $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: It would also be acceptable to refer to the domain as simply $\mathbb{R}^2$, since it is the exact same set that you described.

Comment: What is $z$ a member of?

Comment: z lies in a subset of the $\mathbb R.$  i.e. $z \in [5,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I can't really imagine this curve..."

I'm sure that you are familiar with how $f(x) = 3x^2$ looks like in $(x,f(x))$ plane. Now imagine that you with two fingers grab any point $(x'f(x'))$ on the curve, and that you pull it around the $f(x)$ axis, i.e rotating the function around the axis until you end up at the point in which you started. You now have created the function $g(x,y) = 3x^2 + 3y^2$ and from this you should be able to imagine how $f(x,y) = 3x^2 + 2y^2$ looks like. The $-5$ just moves the function down a bit.

Comment: Interesting way to think about it. Thanks

Comment: This "trick" helped me a lot through imagining the shape of functions in multi-calculus. Once you understand it, it's easy to see how functions like $|x| + |y|, x^2 - y^2, z^2+x^2 + y^2, ... $ looks like. Good luck with the studies. @KSplitX

Comment: Sorry I tried to read this over but just forgot what this sentence means. Can you please explain it. "Grab any point (x',f(x')) <I get this>, and imagine that you pull it around the f(x) axis <so would this be the y axis in our case>"

Comment: Yes, thats what normally is called the y-axis. :) @KSplitX

Comment: Hmmmm ... how do you imagine something like $3x^2 - 2y^2 - 5$, the minus is key?

Comment: Well, once again think of one dim. case. You know how $f(x) = 3x^2, \ g(x) = -2y^2$ looks like. In the $x,y,f(x,y)$ plane, if you only move along the $y,f(x)$ plane, then $x=0$ so the only contribution will be from $-2y^2$ and similary in the $x,f(x)$ plane $y=0$ so the only contribution will be from $3x^2$. So in these two planes you know exactly how it lookes like. Now start rotating one of them and "add up" $3x^2 - 2y^2$. Once again the $-5$ will just shift the graph down. @KSplitX

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^2$ and $y^2 \geq 0$, range $\geq -5$